# Difference between words that mean "take by force": 抢 and 夺

Tags: difference

They are defined in a similar way. What is the difference in usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

抢 -  snatch; **vie for**: '抢' emphasizes the 'contesting' nature of 'taking by force'

夺 -  seize; **compete**; deprive; **decide**: '奪' emphasizes the 'possessing' result of 'taking by force'

> Look at the word [抢夺](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/55938/)  (snatch; seize; take by force; steal):

- 抢 (to snatch) mainly describes the action. If someone is **in the process** of grabbing money by force, we say it is an act of 抢钱, not 夺钱
- 夺 (seize) mainly describes the result. If someone **completed** seizing power from the other, we say it is an act of 夺权, not  抢权 (抢权 imply you are still fighting for the power)

Example with more context:

- '意图夺权' means you 'intend to seize power'; '意图抢权' means 'intend to vie for power'